# Set background color of QtTableWidget cell based on dataframe result condition

Tags: python, pandas, pyqt5

I'm attempting to change the background color of a cell after a specific condition is met in a PyQt5 UI that will be displaying SQL results in a pandas dataframe. My assumption is the condition would need to be set within the QtTableWidget in the process of taking the dataframe results and pasting them into the window, and not through the dataframe.style.apply function. Here is my code at the moment. UI loads successfully, but once I try to load the results, it crashes (does not happen if I'm not putting in this code, and I've learned this means a part of the code is not working).

I've attached a photo of the UI working with results showing. Main goal is to highlight the 'Y' under "In Production" green, and red if 'N'. Can be applied for other columns as well.

```py
def print_output(self):
    file1 = self.result_query()
    file1 = file1[['in production',
                   'rows (prod)',
                   'expected row count',
                   'row check',
                   'export name',
                   'export group',
                   'export id',
                   'export status',
                   'prod export timestamp',
                   'holiday check',
                   'in test',
                   'rows (test)',
                   'test export timestamp',
                   'fixing flag',
                   'export type',
                   'filepath',
                   'synced to production']]
    self.ExportStatusWindow.setColumnCount(len(file1.columns))
    self.ExportStatusWindow.setRowCount(len(file1.index))
    self.ExportStatusWindow.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(file1.columns.str.title())
       for i in range(len(file1.index)):
            for j in range(len(file1.columns)):
                 #where it's posting dataframe results to view
                 self.ExportStatusWindow.setItem(i, j, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(file1.iat[i, j])))
                 #where i'm attempting to change cell color with condition
                 if self.ExportStatusWindow.HorizontalHeaderLabels(file1.columns.str.title('in production')) == 'Y':
                   self.ExportStatusWindow(rowIndex, j).setBackground(QtGui.QColor(green))
                 else:
                   self.ExportStatusWindow(rowIndex, j).setBackground(QtGui.QColor(red))
    self.ExportStatusWindow.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(False)
    self.ExportStatusWindow.resizeColumnsToContents()
    self.ExportStatusWindow.resizeRowsToContents()
    self.ExportStatusWindow.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
```

Example of working UI with results

[image: Example of working UI with results]

Comment: always put full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot)

Comment: There wasn’t an error message. It loads the UI but when I put in the parameters and try to display results, the UI crashes. My screenshot was intended to show what the results look like to explain what I’m trying to accomplish with my code on the highlighting of the results.

Comment: shouldn't be string `"green"` instead of variable `green`

Comment: for additional info:
if i uncomment that code, my UI loads, however, when I click the button to run my script, it freezes and i get a pop up that tells me that "Python has stopped working" and it prompts me to debug through a random program or close program.

Comment: did you run it in console/terminal/cmd.exe to see error message in console ? It could give more useful information.

Comment: when I click to debug, it only gives me the option to debug through microsoft visual studio 2008 or 2010, tho neither works and freezes up pythonw.exe. it does say that "an unhandled win32 exception occurred in pythonw.exe [10512]"

Comment: run in command line using `python.exe` (without `w` in name). It will display error in command line.

Comment: BTW: what value do you have in variable `green` ? `print(green)` ? Maybe it shoud be string `"green"` ?

Comment: I figured out my main issue, however, now i'm not sure how to specify the column for the If condition to set in. I can only have it look through the whole table that is pasted.

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer:

```py
for i in range(len(file1.index)):
    for j in range(len(file1.columns)):
        self.ExportStatusWindow.setItem(i, j, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(file1.iat[i, j])))
        if (self.ExportStatusWindow.item(i, j).column() == 0 and
            self.ExportStatusWindow.item(i, j).text() == 'Y'):
            self.ExportStatusWindow.item(i, j).setBackground(QtGui.QColor("green"))
        elif (self.ExportStatusWindow.item(i, j).column() == 0 and
              self.ExportStatusWindow.item(i, j).text() == 'N'):
              self.ExportStatusWindow.item(i, j).setBackground(QtGui.QColor("red"))
```

My issue was I wasn't looking into the item that I created with the dataframe, I was just looking into the QTableWidget itself.